# Conseguir un string de un objeto y asignarlo a un char

Tags: c++

En mi actividad escolar me pidieron usar campos de dimensión para una actividad, lo que pasa es que guardo un "1" en el objeto y al momento de querer recuperarlo y asignarlo al objeto no me es posible. Me dice que no es constante.

```
char nombreC[30], artistaC[30], generoC[30], idC[2], estatusC[2]; //Así los declaro

//y así lo quiero recuperar "'s' es mi el nombre de mi objeto"
s.setId("1");
idC = s.getId().c_str();
idLen = stoi(s.getId()); //Para el campo de dimensión

//para después guardarlo en un archivo así
songsList.write((char*)&idLen, sizeof(int));
songsList.write((char*)&idC, idLen);
```

ERROR:

```
menu.cpp:53: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'const char*' to 'char [2]'
         idC = s.getId().c_str();
             ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que el tipo de dato que retorna esta función:

```
s.getId().c_str();
```

es un `const char*`

En C no puedes igualar un tipo de dato puntero, que es el que retorna la función, un puntero que apunta a la primera posición de memoria del array que retornas, a un array de dos posiciones directamente de esa manera. Puedes utilizar la función `strcpy`, te pondré un ejemplo a ver si te sirve:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

char * c_str() {
    char *returned_array = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2); //Esta multiplicado por 2 para reservar 2 bytes, ya que cada caracter ocupa 1 byte

    returned_array[0] = 'a';
    returned_array[1] = 'b';

    return returned_array;
}

int main() {

    char idC[2];
    strcpy(idC, c_str());

    //Al printar los valores obtengo como resultado a y b
    cout << idC[0] << endl;
    cout << idC[1] << endl;

}
```

(En la función `c_str()` he puesto un ejemplo cualquiera, lo que importa es que retorna igual que en tu caso un `char*`)

Básicamente lo que hace el `strcpy` es, coger el puntero de `idC` que es el que apunta a la primera posición de ese array y copiar a partir de ahí todos los elementos que tenga el segundo parámetro que le pasas.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Composite, eso resolvió mis dudas, funciona.

Comment: Esta respuesta es correcta en práctica pero incorrecta en forma, además de tener serios errores de concepto. No es adecuada para C++.

Answer (score 3):

En primer lugar debes entender el error del que te informa el compilador:

> ```
> incompatible types in assignment of 'const char*' to 'char [2]'
> ```

El compilador te está indicando que no puedes asignar un `const char*` a un `char [2]` en esta sentencia:

```
//         vvvvv <--- getId devuelve std::string, c_str() devuelve const char*
   idC = s.getId().c_str();
// ~~~ <--- idC es char [2]
```

Efectivamente no se puede asignar un puntero (`const char*`) a una formación<sup>1</sup> de caracteres, el motivo (a parte de por ser tipos distintos) es la categoría de la memoria a la que apuntan.

#### Formaciones de tamaño estático.

Las formaciones de tamaño estático tienen el siguiente formato:

```
tipo nombre[tamaño];
```

El tamaño de la formación debe ser un valor constante conocido en tiempo de compilación, la memoria que ocupa esta formación se asigna en la pila (stack) y está anclada al ámbito en que se crea (se libera automáticamente al salir del ámbito).

#### Memoria dinámica.

La memoria dinámica en C++ sólo puede ser accedida mediante punteros, así que en el código la veremos como:

```
tipo *nombre;
```

No se tiene constancia de la cantidad de memoria a la que apunta el puntero (tamaño del dato) y se aloja en el montón (heap) sin estar anclada a ningún ámbito, debe ser solicitada y liberada por el programador.

#### Tu código.

A parte de no poder asignar entre si dos tipos incompatibles, como hemos visto no puedes asignar entre si memoria que pertenece a categorías distintas, y ese es el motivo del fallo de compilación. Te queda la opción de copiar los datos de un lado en el otro:

```
const auto &id = s.getId();
std::copy(std::begin(id), std::end(id), std::begin(idC));
//             ~~~~~~~~~       ~~~~~~~       ~~~~~~~~~~
//                 ^              ^              ^
//                 |              |              |
// copia         desde          hasta        a partir de
```

O mejor aún, usa los mismos tipos de datos y olvida los problemas de manejar la memoria a mano:

```
std::string idC;

s.setId("1");
idC = s.getId();
idLen = stoi(idC);

songsList.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&idLen), sizeof(idLen));
songsList.write(idC.c_str(), idLen);
```

---

También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.